# Javascript, How to browse subsequently two urls?

Tags: javascript, onload, chain

I have a list of couples of urls, foreach click on a couple urls what I want is to

```
- open a new window (because if it's IFRAME I will get a SAMEORIGIN issue)
- browse url A 
- onload complete url A, browse urlB in the same window instance.
```

List is like:

```
<span onclick="browseChain(urlA, urlB)">first Item</span>


<script>
      function browseChain(urlA, urlB){
         var myPopup = window.open(urlA, 'preview');
         myPopup.addEventListener('load', function(){
            console.log('url open: '+urlB);
            setTimeout("window.open('"+urlB+"', 'preview');", 2000);
         }, false);

      }    
</script>
```

like above seems like Js doesn't intercept "load" event...

Comment: If the pages are not on the same domain it won't work.

Comment: so there's no hack to know if domainA opens in a new window domainB, to get from Js in A when B is loaded (completed)?

Comment: Could you open both new `window` objects from original `window` ? What is purpose of opening third `window` from within second `window` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will work :

JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/r1pgvf3z/1/

```
    <span onclick="browseChain('urlA', 'urlB');">first Item</span>
<script>
function browseChain(urlA, urlB){
console.log("rohit");
         var myPopup = window.open(urlA, 'preview');
         myPopup.addEventListener('load', function(){
            console.log('url open: '+urlB);
            setTimeout("window.open(urlB, 'preview');", 2000);
         }, false);

      } 
      </script>
```